# Second derivative, chain rule and order of operations

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

So the chain rule for second derivatives is $$ \frac {d^2 y} {d t^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac {dy} {dx}) \cdot \frac {dx} {dt} \cdot \frac {dx} {dt} + \frac {dy} {dx} \cdot \frac {d^2 x} {d t^2} = \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} \cdot (\frac {dx} {dt})^2 + \frac {dy} {dx} \cdot \frac {d^2 x} {d t^2}$$

Today I came across this equation in a graphics/computer modeling course

$$\ddot C = \frac {d\dot C} {d \mathbf x} \cdot \dot {\mathbf x} + \frac {dC} {d \mathbf x} \cdot \ddot {\mathbf x}$$

Now what i would infer from this is that

$$\frac {d} {dx}(\frac {dy} {dx}) \cdot \frac {dx} {dt} = \frac {d} {dx}(\frac {dy} {dx} \cdot \frac {dx} {dt}) =\frac {d\dot y} { dx}$$

This sounds right but can someone point me to a rule or theorem that suggests that ? can the $dx/dt$ be moved in and out of the $d()/dt$ operator ??

Comment: Unless $\dot{x}=0$ I don't see that it is true. I think your second equation, the one you came across, is flawed.

Comment: @ancientmathematician would it matter if x in their equation was a vector? C in their slides is "Constraint Function" for a particle with position x. maybe i'm drawing analogies i should not be drawing between vectors and scalar differentiation. Here is a link if you can look [page 14].. https://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2014/cs7496_fall/slides/ConstrDyn.pdf

Comment: I don't see that it does: after all the general case would have to cover the case with dimension $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician same here but thought i would check myself. Thanks for taking the time to look at this

Comment: I find the whole set of slides puzzling. Lots of things are asserted to be $0$ which are surely only $0$ at $t=0$.